# Download link takes guest customers to a login

Tags: magento2, customer-account, downloadable, guest-checkout, download-link

Forgive me if this has already been answered somewhere.

I am using Magento version 2.0.7-0 CE with the Luma theme.

I am planning to sell downloadable files from my website.

File sharing is disabled, and needs to remain as such.

I'm testing everything in demo store mode, and using a PayPal sandbox account.

I have checkout as guest enabled, but when I click the download link in the confirmation e-mail at the e-mail address that I gave during checkout, I am taken back into my store's site to sign in, in order to download the file.  What I want to happen instead is for the guest customer to be able to click the download link and actually download the file, without logging into my website.

Is there a feature/module/switch in Magento's backend that does what I want?

I have looked at:

[Downloadable products unique external URL for each order](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/109035/downloadable-products-unique-external-url-for-each-order?rq=1)

and

https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/94728/link-to-download-product-in-order-email-breaking

and others.

My Google searches have not panned out.

Concerning the above situation, I have looked at Marketing> Email Templates> Load default template> and Previewed Templates, but nothing said "Order Confirmation", so I guess I will have to make my own custom email template and reference it in "New Order Confirmation Template for Guest" in STORES > Settings > Configuration > SALES > Sales Emails.  If I get the guest direct download to work, and I make a new template, will Magento automatically make a single-use download link for my template?

If there isn't anything to change in the backend to achieve what I want, I am a programmer and I can write code in PHP, JavaScript, and HTML, and would just need to be pointed in the right direction so that I can write a solution, but I would prefer a backend solution instead of changing the Magento files.

Thanks everyone.

Comment: any solutions for this?

Answer (score 0):

Guest Checkout will only work when "Shareable" is set to Yes.

Thanks